# Correct translation of 我司言开宗立派到如今

Tags: translation

The sentence is:

> 我司言开宗立派到如今。

I translated this as "I 司言 started a school and established a political group until now".

I already tried with online translators but they all gave me different meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume 司言 is a name.

派 in 开宗立派 is not referred to as "political group" (政治派系). but a  "school of/ style " (門派)

Literal translation: "I, Si Yan, established this school/ style till today

- 宗派 mostly refers to a branch of religion, e.g. 遜尼派 (Sunni)
- 派 mostly refers to a martial art style, e.g. 詠春派 (Wing Chun Style)

Using it metaphorically to describe a  "political group" is kind of fitting, since there is a lot of similarities between a political group and a school of martial art (there are leaders and followers, and they all work toward the same ideal) Therefore,  "I, Si Yin, established a political party until now". would be correct if it really was a political group and not a school of martial art

Comment: Thank for your answer!
But now i have another question , the sentence doesn't have a Verb1 Object2 Verb2 Object2 structure as 开 V1 with 宗 O1 and 立 V2 with 派 O2 ??

Comment: @Eduardo S 开宗立派 = 开立(v - start and  establish) + 宗派(n - school of style).

Answer (score 1):

"宗", "派" both mean "a main branch of the under-word society (武林, 江湖, 黑社會), the equivalent in English is the "Family" (Mafia Family), or "cult".

开宗立派 - Creating, building and controlling the family.

**Response to Comments:**

在中國, "宗", "派"一般指門派 - such as 少林,武當,崑崙,峨嵋,密宗, all are related to 宗派 or 教派 (佛教,道教,喇嘛教), and have inseparable connections to 武林 and 江湖. For example - 武當開山祖"张三丰".同時也是中國武學的鼻祖;又如,少林派創少林拳,十八銅人陣...門派 also includes 幫派 (gangs - such as 青幫, 洪幫, 丐幫, 鹽幫...), and 教派 (such as 白蓮教, 日月教-魔教 and most recently - 法轮功).

Most of the above are cult-like, or clan-like groups, they are/were quite active in the "underworld - 武林, 江湖"; also, similar to the mafia, some (幫派) are/were very active in the gang-world (黑社會), though their activities and actions can be referred to as " both good and evil (亦正亦邪)".

My answer has omitted 派系 in the political (黨派) and entertainment (流派) arenas. The former is too board to cover (古自法家道家,今至共產民主之爭!); the latter concerns the different styles of signing and expressions in the Ancient Chinese Musical/Opera, such as "程派艺术", 以程砚秋為其(开宗立派)创始人(宗師), and "梅派唱腔", 以梅兰芳為其(开宗立派)起始人(宗師). Again, this is too board to be adequately covered in here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132597/discussion-on-answer-by-r13-correct-translation-of-).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 派 is necessarily 黑社会帮派。

出现了开宗立派的专业画家、书法家。
A number of virtuosos emerged in Chinese calligraphy and painting.

清代铁岭籍画家高其佩被公认为指画开宗立派的创始人。
Gao Qipei, a painter from Tieling in the Qing Dynasty, is recognized as the founder of the  School of Finger Painting.

So I, Pedroski, without further context, would translate:

我司言开宗立派到如今。
I, Si Yan, founded a school （of thought or whatever） which still exists today.

PS: 司言 was a job title （唐代官职）

司言，读音sī yán，汉语词语，意思是担任中书舍人。